# Google Calendar's "This and following events" option when deleting a recurring event

Tags: google-calendar

When deleting a recurring event in Google Calendar, I only receive the option of deleting "This and following events" sometimes. When this option is not available, my only options are to delete the single event or "All events", which I believe removes all instances of an event from my calendar, even if I've been attending for years, making my historical calendar inaccurate.

So "This and following events" is usually ideal when I'm deleting an event that will go on without me, but what are the conditions for seeing this option? Does it only show when you're the event owner?

[image: Delete recurring event]

Comment: You asked: "Does it only show when you're the event owner?" I get this problem on some events, but not on others, and that does not seem to be the differentiating factor.

Comment: maybe the differentiating factor is whether you have permission to edit the event.
still annoying

Answer (score 1):

You will see "This and following events" option if it is a recurring event that has instances in the future AND when you have edit permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it only shows on some events is that it only gives you that option on events that you have edit permissions for. The two cases in which this could happen are:

1. You are the owner of the event
2. The owner of the event gave you editing permissions when or after adding you to the event

Comment: Is there a way to know whether #2 it true or false?